# Web Audio API oscillator won't make any sound

Tags: web-audio-api, javascript-oscillator

I'm trying to test a simple oscillator not attached to any world object on the scene. Simply a tone, but following the [example for a oscillator node](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/OscillatorNode) does not seem to play anything. Does it require some kind of user interaction first to be allowed to play?

I also have a cube rotating on the scene, but it shouldn't affect anything. The script:

```
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );

var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry();
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x00ff00 } );
var cube = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
scene.add( cube );

camera.position.z = 5;

function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame( animate );

    cube.rotation.x += 0.05;
    cube.rotation.y += 0.01;

    renderer.render( scene, camera );
}
animate();


// create web audio api context
var audioCtx = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();

// create Oscillator node
var oscillator = audioCtx.createOscillator();

oscillator.type = 'square';
oscillator.frequency.setValueAtTime(440, audioCtx.currentTime); // value in hertz
var gainNode = audioCtx.createGain();
oscillator.connect(gainNode);
oscillator.connect(audioCtx.destination);

var initialFreq = 3000;
var initialVol = 0.500;

gainNode.gain.value = initialVol;
gainNode.gain.minValue = initialVol;
gainNode.gain.maxValue = initialVol;

oscillator.frequency.value = 3000;

oscillator.start();
```

Comment: You’re connecting the oscillator to the gain mode and also to the context destination... shouldn’t it be the oscillator to the gain node and then the gain mode to the destination?

Comment: I don't know, but when I connect he gain node to the destination, it still does not play sound.

Comment: I just copied and pasted your code (starting at `var audioCtx` and below) onto my browser console, and the tone played with no problems. Are you saying the audio stops playing only when you add the 3D cube to the page?

Comment: That’s interesting. Are you able to hear other web audio examples? For instance, this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dsuket/jTh3v/

Comment: Yes that and other examples play fine. I haven't been able to understand the difference. Maybe it requires user interaction, but I've also seen examples that play straight away. Tried deleting my cache. Still, nothing. Now I'm trying to adopt one that seems like it works that requires user interaction.

Comment: Check the console log to see if the audiocontext was blocked from playing because of the autoplay policy.  You need some kind of user-gesture to get the context to run.